# unexpected behaviors of jQuery is hidden and slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use jquery to slideshow and hide texts.
hide text with css code bellow,

```
.mainContent>.imageInfo:nth-child(1){
  display:none;
}
.mainContent>.imageInfo:nth-child(2)
{
   display:none;
}
.mainContent>.imageInfo:nth-child(3){
   display:none;
}
.mainContent>.imageInfo:nth-child(4){
   display:none;
}
```

and the item hovered is supposed to show THAT ITEM's left-bottom-corner text block.

```
 $( ".colContainer >  .mainContent:nth-child(n)" ).hover(function () {
       var $sel=$(".mainContent>.imageInfo:nth-child(" +( $(this).index() + 1)+")");


       if ( $sel.is( ":hidden" ) ) {
           $sel.slideDown( "slow" );console.log("hid");
        } else {
           $sel.hide();console.log("show");
        }
 });
```

but, as gif shows, nothing happened when I hover the first 2 elements, and when I hover the third element, it's supposed to show its own text; it shows all left-bottom-corner text blocks though.

code,
https://jsfiddle.net/Debra321/j9kkx4no/127/

Any comments are welcome and appreciated.

*I have confirmed that it's not caused by trivial errors like typo.

My observation is that there are 2 problems: one is $sel.hide are mistakenly called even though the item is already hidden now. Two is that the 3rd item selector in some way shows every text block. When hovering, console.log prints messages.

[image]

Comment: this can be much easily done with css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easiest to do in CSS as explained in following code.

Though for mobile sites/apps; hover is not a good interaction as you can not hover on mobiles.

It is not working in jQuery because in line `var $sel = $(".mainContent>.imageInfo:nth-child(" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ")");`; the `nth-child` selector should be on `.mainContent` rather than `.imageInfo`.

`.imageInfo` will always be 3rd child inside the `.mainContnet`, that's why it was hsowing only when you hover on the 3rd tile (`index` is 2 and `nth-child` is `index+1`, i.e. 3).

So it can be written as `var $sel = $(".mainContent:nth-child(" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ")>.imageInfo");`

```js
(function() {
  var dataObj =
    `{
        "widget": {
            "story": {
               "subtitle": "My",
               "maintitle": "Story",
               "desc": "A life as a daughter, sister and programer.",
               "image": "http://gdurl.com/USQR",
               "imageinfo":"Hsinchu",
               "spriteiconpos":"0 0",
               "url": "#"
           },
        "work": {
            "subtitle": "Working",
            "maintitle": "Experience",
            "desc": "Learning, Studying and Training.",
            "image": "http://gdurl.com/USQR",
            "imageinfo":"San Francisco",
            "spriteiconpos":"-80px 0",
            "url": "#"
        },
        "interests": {
            "subtitle": "Personal",
            "maintitle": "Interests",
            "desc": "Paint life with colors of interests.",
            "image": "http://gdurl.com/USQR",
            "imageinfo":"Quebec",
            "spriteiconpos":"0 -80px",
            "url": "#"
        },
        "goals": {
            "subtitle":"Future",
            "maintitle":"Goals",
            "desc": "Do not just survive.",
            "image": "http://gdurl.com/USQR",
            "imageinfo":"Quebec",
            "spriteiconpos":"-80px -80px",
            "url": "#"
        }
       }
     }`;
  var dataObj = $.parseJSON(dataObj);
  var dataArray = $.map(dataObj["widget"], function(value, index) {
    return [value];
  });
  var htmlCode = "";
  for (var i in dataArray) {
    var cssAttr = "";
    var cssSelect = "";
    //html
    htmlCode += "<div class='mainContent'>";
    htmlCode += "<div class='mainCol'>";
    htmlCode += "<h2>" + dataArray[i].subtitle + "</h2>";
    htmlCode += "<h1>" + dataArray[i].maintitle + "</h1>";
    htmlCode += "<p>" + dataArray[i].desc + "</p>";
    htmlCode += "</div>";
    htmlCode += "<i class='i-caretRight'></i>";
    htmlCode += "<div class='imageInfo'>" + dataArray[i].imageinfo + "</div>";
    htmlCode += "</div>";
    //css
    cssAttr = "background: url(http://gdurl.com/USQR) " + dataArray[i].spriteiconpos + "  no-repeat";
    cssSelect = ".colContainer >  .mainContent:nth-child(" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + "):before";
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
    var rules = sheet.rules;
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule(cssSelect, cssAttr, rules.length);


  }
  $("#phoneContent .colContainer").html(htmlCode);
})();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allura|Habibi|Asar');
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #fcfca4;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #F3E9D2, #EC9192);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
}

#phoneContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17.7%;
  left: 50px;
  width: 253px;
  height: 455px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mainPhoneContent {
  top: 0;
  height: 90%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background: #c7c4be url(http://gdurl.com/ist4) repeat;
}

.phoneToolBar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
}

#phoneContent .colContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110%;
  display: flex;
  top: 15%;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 7px 50px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 7px 50px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
  box-shadow: 4px 7px 50px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
}

.colContainer>.mainContent {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  background: #f1efe4;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0f0e5, #e7e5da);
}

.mainContent>.imageInfo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  bottom: -100%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 23%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Allura, serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: black;
  transition: bottom linear 0.2s;
}

.mainContent:hover>.imageInfo {
  bottom: 1%;
}

.mainContent>.mainCol {
  left: 40%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.mainCol>h2 {
  font-family: 'Habibi', serif;
  color: #ff7519;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.mainCol>h1 {
  font-family: 'Habibi', serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: -12%;
}

.mainCol>p {
  margin-top: -10%;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1.45;
  color: #383838;
}

.colContainer>.mainContent:nth-child(n) {
  position: relative;
}

.colContainer>.mainContent:nth-child(n):hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.colContainer>.mainContent:nth-child(n):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 2%;
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.mainContent>i {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  right: 3%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.mainContent>i:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #b8b7b0;
  content: "";
  transform-origin: right top;
  -ms-transform-origin: right top;
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform-origin: right top;
  /* Firefox */
  -o-transform-origin: right top;
  /* Opera */
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.mainContent>i:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #b8b7b0;
  content: "";
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  -ms-transform-origin: right bottom;
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform-origin: right bottom;
  /* Firefox */
  -o-transform-origin: right bottom;
  /* Opera */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #DBDDDD;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st2 {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}

.st3 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #E5E5E5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st4 {
  opacity: 0.3;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

#myPhone {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 700px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="myPhone">
    <div id="phonediv">
      <svg version="1.1" id="phone" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 250 500" style="enable-background:new 0 0 250 500;" xml:space="preserve">
     <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M21,104.5c0,1.4-1.1,2.5-2.5,2.5l0,0c-1.4,0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5v-18c0-1.4,1.1-2.5,2.5-2.5l0,0
  c1.4,0,2.5,1.1,2.5,2.5V104.5z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M21,143.5c0,1.4-1.1,2.5-2.5,2.5l0,0c-1.4,0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5v-18c0-1.4,1.1-2.5,2.5-2.5l0,0
  c1.4,0,2.5,1.1,2.5,2.5V143.5z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M21,182.5c0,1.4-1.1,2.5-2.5,2.5l0,0c-1.4,0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5v-18c0-1.4,1.1-2.5,2.5-2.5l0,0
  c1.4,0,2.5,1.1,2.5,2.5V182.5z"/>
     </g>
     <path class="st0" d="M200.5,23.3H53.7c-22.6,0-35.1,15.2-35.1,34.4v387.9c0,21.4,16.6,35.1,35.1,35.1h146.8
 c19.7,0,34.4-15.9,34.4-35.1V57.7C234.9,38.5,221.9,23.3,200.5,23.3z M217.6,414.6H35.1V87.2h182.5V414.6z"/>
     <path class="st0" d="M200.5,476.2H53.7c-14.7,0-30.6-11.7-30.6-30.6V57.7c0-17,13.2-29.9,30.6-29.9h146.8
 c16.7,0,29.9,13.1,29.9,29.9v387.9C230.4,461.6,216.1,476.2,200.5,476.2z M53.7,28.6c-17,0-29.9,12.5-29.9,29.1v387.9
 c0,20.4,17.8,29.9,29.9,29.9h146.8c15.2,0,29.1-14.2,29.1-29.9V57.7c0-16.3-12.8-29.1-29.1-29.1H53.7z"/>
     <circle class="st1" cx="127.1" cy="445.2" r="19.9"/>
         <g>
            <path class="st2" d="M127.1,427.1c10.4,0,18.9,8.5,18.9,18.9c0,10.4-8.5,18.9-18.9,18.9c-10.4,0-18.9-8.5-18.9-18.9
  C108.2,435.6,116.7,427.1,127.1,427.1 M127.1,426.1c-11,0-19.9,8.9-19.9,19.9c0,11,8.9,19.9,19.9,19.9c11,0,19.9-8.9,19.9-19.9
  C147,435,138.1,426.1,127.1,426.1L127.1,426.1z"/>
         </g>
         <path class="st3" d="M131.2,453.6h-9c-1.7,0-3-1.4-3-3v-9c0-1.7,1.4-3,3-3h9c1.7,0,3,1.4,3,3v9C134.2,452.3,132.9,453.6,131.2,453.6
 z M122.2,439.4c-1.2,0-2.3,1-2.3,2.3v9c0,1.2,1,2.3,2.3,2.3h9c1.2,0,2.3-1,2.3-2.3v-9c0-1.2-1-2.3-2.3-2.3H122.2z"/>
         <path class="st0" d="M146,50.5c0,1.4-1.1,2.5-2.5,2.5h-35c-1.4,0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5l0,0c0-1.4,1.1-2.5,2.5-2.5h35
 C144.9,48,146,49.1,146,50.5L146,50.5z"/>
        <line class="st4" x1="34.5" y1="87" x2="217" y2="87"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="phoneContent">
      <div id="mainPhoneContent">
        <div class="colContainer">
        </div>
        <!--colContainer-->
      </div>
      <div class="phoneToolBar"></div>
    </div>
    <!--phoneContent-->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! I see using transition instead. But there are still some issues: one is that the last item's text block is visible when mouse scroll to bottom; two is that I don't know why when I focus an item with mouse, the the component shakes. please see my attachment.

Comment: you can check it now

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks fine, and do you know why the jquery version doesn't work out? I am curious.

Comment: And if I use iphone 6s safari to browse the new solution, the component still shakes.. :'(  when scrolling elastically to the bottom.

Comment: reason for jQuery version not working also added; though you need to inspect the iOS safari to see why it is shaking.